# Selecting certain links with a REGEX

Tags: php, regex, pattern-matching

I'm working to do a "Wiki Game" with PHP, and i'd like to match all the links in a string starting by `/wiki/something`, for example `/wiki/Chiffrement_RSA` or `/wiki/OSS_117_:_Le_Caire,_nid_d%27espions`. I know just a few thigs about REGEX, so I'm struct. If someone could help me, it would be nice.
For the time, I just have `\/wiki\/*`...
Thanks for your help !

Comment: I would recommend using the strpos as outlined below. But if you want to use a regex, this catches everything up to the first space, then \/wiki\/([^ ]+)  works. If you're interested in testing regex's, try http://regexr.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally chose Cody.code's answer with this regex : `\/wiki\/([^ ]+)`. 
I will use this code to check if i keep a link in an array or not (I will parse my html with DOMDocument an get all the `<a>`, it's faster) , so the `preg_match()` solution is the best for me, instead of strpos. 
Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 2):

You can do by regex or [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php):

```
<?php
$mystring = 'abc';
$find   = '/wiki/';
$statusLink = strpos($mystring, $find);

// Note our use of ===.  Simply == would not work as expected
// because the position of 'a' was the 0th (first) character.
if ($statusLink === false) {
    echo "Not the link that you want";
} else {
    echo "You found the link";
}

 //or by explode
  $link = explode('/', $originalLink);
  if ($link[1] == 'wiki' && isset($link[2])){
    //is your link
  }
?>
```

[I don't use pure regex so much unless it's very necessary.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/998997/should-i-avoid-regular-expressions)

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce your output array size by by 50% using `\K` in your pattern.  It eliminates the need for a capture group and puts your desired substrings in the "fullstrings" array.

Pattern:

```
\/wiki\/\K[^ ]+
```

`\K` says "start the fullstring match from here".  This means no memory waste.  It may be a microimprovement, but I believe it to be best practice and I think more people should use it.