# How to get sub string before special character?

Tags: javascript, string, split

Below code is giving me expected result "1524587" but right side could be `-0`, `-1` etc , so how to grab left side string before `-` ? my 2nd option is not returning the left string

main.js

```
const str = "1524587-0";
// 1st option 
const rxNumber = element.str .replace('-0', '');

// 2nd Option 
const  splitstring = str.split('-')
```

Comment: try parseInt("1524587-0")

Comment: I found this: [How to grab substring before a specified character jQuery or JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9133102/how-to-grab-substring-before-a-specified-character-jquery-or-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

You can split using using the character `-` and then getting the first array value of the result :

```js
var str = "1524587-0".split('-');
console.log(str[0]);
```

Using the same logic you'd use `words[1]` to get the right side of the string :

```js
var str = "1524587-0".split('-');
console.log(str[1]);
```

[In short](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), this function splits a String object into an array of strings by separating the string into substrings, using a specified separator string to determine where to make each split.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex as well

```
/[^-]*/.exec("1524587-0")[0]
```

or split

```
"1524587-0".split('-')[0]
```

Comment: [Don't use regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/998997/should-i-avoid-regular-expressions#999051) when you can do the same thing without them.