# How to get rid of duplicates in regex

Tags: c#, regex, duplicates

Suppose I had a string, "cats cats cats and dogs dogs dogs."

What regular expression would I use in order to replace that string with,"cats and dogs." i.e. removing duplicates. The expression however must only remove duplicates that follow after each other. For instance:

"cats cats cats and dogs dogs dogs and cats cats and dogs dogs"

Would return:

"cats and dogs and cats and dogs"

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058783/regular-expression-to-find-and-remove-duplicate-words it might give you some pointers on your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `(\w+)\s+\1` with `$1`

Do this in a loop until no more matches are found. Setting the `global` flag is not enough as it wouldn't replace third `cats` in  `cats cats cats`

`\1` in regex refers to the contents of the first captured group.

Try:

```
str = "cats cats cats and dogs dogs dogs and cats cats and dogs dogs";
str = Regex.Replace(str, @"(\b\w+\b)\s+(\1(\s+|$))+", "$1 ");
Console.WriteLine(str);
```

Comment: I'm using this code: replacer = Regex.Replace(replacer, @"([\\n]+)[\s+]?\1", string.Empty); but it doesn't seem to work. It works in rubular though http://www.rubular.com/r/Ey6wrLYXNw

Comment: @Emmanuel Try `str = Regex.Replace(str, @"(\w+)\s+\1", "$1");`

Answer (score 9):

```
resultString = Regex.Replace(subjectString, @"\b(\w+)(?:\s+\1\b)+", "$1");
```

will do all replacements in one single call.

Explanation:

```
\b                 # assert that we are at a word boundary
                   # (we only want to match whole words)
(\w+)              # match one word, capture into backreference #1
(?:                # start of non-capturing, repeating group
   \s+             # match at least one space
   \1              # match the same word as previously captured
   \b              # as long as we match it completely
)+                 # do this at least once
```

Comment: Tim, you're a regex guru. Respect! :)

Comment: +1, because the expression works and moreover it is explained.

Answer (score 1):

No doubt there is a smaller regex possible, but this one seems to do the trick:

```
string somestring = "cats cats cats and dogs dogs dogs and cats cats and dogs dogs";
Regex regex = new Regex(@"(\w+)\s(?:\1\s)*(?:\1(\s|$))");
string result = regex.Replace(somestring, "$1$2");
```

It also takes into account the last "dogs" not ending with a space.

Comment: This will remove too many spaces: `cats cats cats and dogs dogs dogs and cats cats and dogs dogs` becomes `catsand dogsand catsand dogs`. It also matches too much: `Michael Bolton on CD` becomes `Michael BoltonCD`. Sorry about the Office Space reference.

Comment: Weird, I can't seem to reproduce those errors. Perhaps I should add some more pieces of flair :]

Comment: Oops, I missed that you are replacing with `$1$2`, so the first problem I thought I saw is not there. But Michael Bolton still has a problem. Perhaps some hypnosis will help (or a word boundary `\b` before the `\w`).

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code.

---

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
   /// <summary>
   ///
   ///  A description of the regular expression:
   ///
   ///  Match expression but don't capture it. [^|\s+]
   ///      Select from 2 alternatives
   ///          Beginning of line or string
   ///          Whitespace, one or more repetitions
   ///  [1]: A numbered capture group. [(\w+)(?:\s+|$)]
   ///      (\w+)(?:\s+|$)
   ///          [2]: A numbered capture group. [\w+]
   ///              Alphanumeric, one or more repetitions
   ///          Match expression but don't capture it. [\s+|$]
   ///              Select from 2 alternatives
   ///                  Whitespace, one or more repetitions
   ///                  End of line or string
   ///  [3]: A numbered capture group. [\1|\2], one or more repetitions
   ///      Select from 2 alternatives
   ///          Backreference to capture number: 1
   ///          Backreference to capture number: 2
   ///
   ///
   /// </summary>
   class Class1
    {
        /// 
        /// Point d'entrée principal de l'application.
        /// 
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Regex regex = new Regex(
                "(?:^|\s+)((\w+)(?:\s+|$))(\1|\2)+",
                RegexOptions.IgnoreCase
                | RegexOptions.Compiled
                );
            string str = "cats cats cats and dogs dogs dogs and cats cats and dogs dogs";
            string regexReplace = " $1";

Console.WriteLine("Before :" + str);

        str = regex.Replace(str,regexReplace);

        Console.WriteLine("After :" + str);
    }
}

}