# How to find a 2-times string in a string using Java Pattern and Matcher?

Tags: java, regex

For example, I want to find a string contains the below string.

```
<a href="http://www.abc.com/Cool">Cool</a>
```

The "Cool" can be any string but must the same at those 2 places.

How to use Pattern and Matcher to achieve this?
Thanks!

Comment: Very similar:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058783/regular-expression-to-find-and-remove-duplicate-words

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<a href="http://www\.abc\.com/([^"]*)">\1</a>
```

matches the string as specified. So, in Java:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("<a href=\"http://www\\.abc\\.com/([^\"]*)\">\\1</a>");
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
foundMatch = regexMatcher.find();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you attempted a simple approach yet such as making a list of all unique words and then looping through each word, checking the occurrence count in the original string?  The simple regex \b\w+\b matches words.

[Here's an article](http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/Java/Regular-Expressions/7/) explaining how to match consecutive duplicate words.  You should be able to adapt this easily to your needs.