# Parse HTML Document?

Tags: c#

How  i can replace image's source , html text saved in database ?

thanks

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56107/what-is-the-best-way-to-parse-html-in-c

Answer (score 4):

You should try the [HTML Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex).

Comment: Good for html, but keep in mind that it is buggy with pure xml

Comment: I hadn't tried the HTML Agility Pack for XML, given that there is a wide variety of libraries dedicated to manipulating XML documents.

Answer (score 0):

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/regexp/thread/37f46a25-113c-420d-aab8-eea98d341189

```
string s = "<img src='1.jpg'><img src='2.jpg'><img src='3.jpg'><img src='4.jpg'>";
string pattern = @"<img\s+src\s*=\s*["']([^"']+)["']\s*/*>";
string output = string.Empty;
output = Regex.Replace(s, pattern, "[Image: $1]");
```

[Regex to get src value from an img tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058852/regex-to-get-src-value-from-an-img-tag)