# How to write regex in C# to get inner value of <p class="mojeip">12.45.45.47</p>?

Tags: c#, regex

Hello I trying to get inner HTML of `<p class="mojeip">12.45.45.47</p>` in C#,
i tried something like>

```
    Regex emailregex = new Regex(@"(<p class=""mojeip"">)(.*?)(</p>)");
```

But still cannot get only IP address.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams: Wow, that's _way_ better than the one I found: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058852/regex-to-get-src-value-from-an-img-tag

Comment: LINQ to XML would make it trivial to get this information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sure you are going to get plenty of RegEx solutions. So I want to propose an alternate solution.

I have often used RegEx to extract data from HTML, but more recently I have used the [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) and I would highly recommend that if it does not feel like too much of an overkill for your task.

Comment: +1. The required XPath would be `//p[@class='mojeip']/text()`

Answer (score 0):

If your input string is exactly this complicated and no more, then you could try capturing `([^<]*)` instead of `(.*?)`. In real life, you're probably trying to parse HTML or XHTML, and almost certainly want to use a tool other than regex, as per Ignacio's comment above.

Answer (score 0):

Regex's are not good for HTML because it is not a regular language.

If you want just this simple action you may use string manipulation and Linq:

```
   string s = @"<p class=""mojeip"">12.45.45.47</p>";

   var result = s.Skip(s.IndexOf(@"""mojeip""") +
                @"""mojeip""".Length + 1).TakeWhile(c => c != '<').ToArray();

   Console.WriteLine(new string(result));
```

Answer (score 0):

This query should do it:

```
(?<=<[^/].*?>).*(?=</.*>)
```

Only parse XML/HTML with Regex if invoking tools like LINQ to XML and such is out of the question for performance or whatever reasons tho.