# How to get src="" from html image tag

Tags: php

```
$str = "html code here and img tag";
preg_match_all('~<img ([^>]+)>~i', $str, $matches);
$images = array();
foreach ($matches[1] as $str) {
    preg_match_all('~([a-z]([a-z0-9]*)?)=("|\')(.*?)("|\')~is', $str, $pairs);
}
```

I can't get SRC from IMG, how to ideas ?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058852/regex-to-get-src-value-from-an-img-tag

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend you consider using [simplehtmldom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) instead of parsing out your img src tags with regular expressions.

```
$html = file_get_html('...html...');

// Find all images & echo src
foreach($html->find('img') as $element)
       echo $element->src . '<br>';
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use an XML parser in PHP like Simple HTML Dom, or a regex for something like this should also work.

```
/src="([^"]*)"/i
```